# How well can you run OS X on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3

I am thinking about buying a Raspberry Pi 3 just to run OS X 10.11. How well will it work based on the Mac specs vs. Pi 3 specs?

Comment: Unfortunately, the model of processor makes it unable to run any desktop OSs you are familiar with. If you want to try iOS (since iPhones have the same core), you may be up for a challenge, but be my guest. Even the Linux distros for the Raspberry Pi are specially made.

Answer (score 7):

As there is no OS X 10.11 version for the ARMv8 architecture, this plan will not work and the answer to your question is: It will not work well, actually, it will not work at all.

Comment: Also, it is illegal :3